# get all proto functions from object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I have an object and i can get all function in it.but i want add function with **proto** then get all function.how can i do?

```
var myObj = {
    func1:function(){}
};
var myPrototype = {
    func2: function(){          
    }
};
myObj.__proto__ = myPrototype;
alert(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myObj));
```

the result is

```
func1
```

but i want all the functions

```
func1,func2
```

how can i do this??????

Comment: use a for-in loop,or Object.keys(myObj.__proto__)

Answer (score 1):

As the method name says, [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) does only get you the *own* property names, not the inherited ones.

To get those as well, you'd need to apply it on the prototype as well - in fact, on all prototypes. Btw, avoid using the [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) property.

```
var myPrototype = {
    func2: function() {}
};
var myObj = Object.create(myPrototype);
myObj.func1 = function(){};
```

```
for (var o=myObj; o!=null; o=Object.getPrototypeOf(o))
    alert(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o));
```

Answer (score 0):

tnx.
i do it by this function

```
function getAllMethods(obj) {
  var result = [];
  for (var id in obj) {
    try {
      if (typeof(obj[id]) == "function") {
        result.push(id + ": " + obj[id].toString());
      }
    }
    catch (err) {
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```